# Getting the mean Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a DataFrame on Python/Pandas that has these columns:

ride_id rideable_type   started_at  ended_at    month   day hour    length_duration start_station_name  start_station_id    end_station_name    end_station_id  start_lat   start_lng   end_lat end_lng member_casual

I would like to get the length_duration average of member type only.
I'm not getting an error but it just loads saying "executing" and nothing happens.
I'm using the following code:

round(df[df["member_casual"] == "member"]["length_duration"].mean(), 1)

am I wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is code I'm trying to use.
round(df[df["member_casual"] == "member"]["length_duration"].mean(), 1)

Answer (score 0):

Use groupby on member_casual so that you will get all aggregated values for each type of member_casual

```
temp=df.groupby("member_casual").get_group("member")
temp.describe()["length_duration"].loc[["mean"]]
```

And then **round()** it off

Comment: Let me know if this works out

Comment: It does not work. 
It says this "Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor"